# Multi-line edit starting at the same character (= sign) [no macros?]

Tags: vim, vi

I'm working on an ansible playbook, where VIm seems to prove to be an extremely useful tool for (lots of similar patterns in style/formatting and such), and I'm hoping to take my current situation (since been written) to turn it into a Vim lesson.

I've made extensive use of code blocks to make multi-line edits, but I think I've reached their limit and wanted to reach out to figure out how I might approach making line edits more dynamically. In this scenario, I have a block of code that I'm trying to transform

from:

```
rcon.port=25575
rcon.password=strong-password
enable-rcon=true
```

into:

```
- { regexp: '^rcon.port', line: 'rcon.port=25575' }
- { regexp: '^rcon.password', line: 'rcon.password=strong-password' }
- { regexp: '^enable-rcon', line: 'enable-rcon=true' }
```

To do that, the first part is fairly simple. Shift-I, then ctrl-V for block, traverse lines to edit, type `- { regexp: '^"` to get to the following:

```
- { regexp: '^rcon.port=25575
- { regexp: '^rcon.password=strong-password
- { regexp: '^enable-rcon=true
```

Unfortunately, from there I'm a bit lost as the macros (and whether or not that's overkill or not) are still a bit unclear to me. Are there any possible approaches to solve this problem other than macros?

I'm not looking for a full solution, but simply a hint for the best (or only approach) here, and if there are any tricks to thinking about this in the Vim way.

Any links to good documentation/learning resources for macros would be AWESOME as well! I'm still new to Vim, so bear with me... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following regular expression substitutions:

```
:%s/^\(.*\)$/- { regexp: '^\1' }/
```

Or with all relevant lines visually selected:

CTRL-o

```
:s/^\(.*\)$/- { regexp: '^\1' }/
```

I guess I should explain that a bit more:

: Enter command mode.

% Apply to all lines.

s Substitute.

/xxx/yyy/ Replace xxx with yyy.

^ Anchor at start of input string

(xxx) (in match string) capture whatever matches xxx.

\1 (in replacement string) replace with whatever matched (xxx).

.* Match any amount of any characters.

$ Anchor at end of input string.

Replacement string is emitted into the result literally without any interpretation, except for stuff like \1.

Answer (score 3):

Building off [@Stephen Warren's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60768006/5872345) answer the following works as required:

```
:%s/^\(\(.\+\)=.\+\)/- regex: '\2', line: '\1' }/
```

The match section is:

- From the beginning of the line `^`
- It has two groups rather than one `\(\)`

  - The first group is the outer one that matches the entire line
  - The second group is the inner group that matches up to the `=`
- Match one or more characters `\+` is used rather than the greedy `*` for matching either side of the `=`

The replace section:

- Basically your expected output calling on the previously matched groups `\1` and `\2`

Comment: How about using very magic `:%s/^\v((.{-})\=.+)/- { regex: '^\2', line: '\1' }`

Comment: Noice. For OP `:help \v`

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess I forgot about replacing the = and adding line: into the output!